# Big Data in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, bigdata

With so many social networks, new services and ubiquitous computing the new age of [big data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Data) is finally here and is difficult to imagine a future without [huge amounts of data](http://www.slideshare.net/bigdatalandscape/the-big-data-landscape). It seems in languages like Java there are popular platforms like [Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) with a great ecosystem.

I wonder what is the state of art in Smalltalk. Is anyone doing big data with Smalltalk? Any libraries, applications or experience reports? Recommendations or advices?

Comment: There are a few Gemstone installations that qualify as Big Data. On the other hand, 95% of all business software needs less than 4G, so it still isn't relevant for the large majority of developers. In smalltalk we tend not to need fancy frameworks to do this kind of thing, so the scaling is mostly solved at application level.

Comment: Too many people don't understand what a good question is for SO. None of the closers seem qualified.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question, it should be reopened

Comment: I am doing big data with Smalltalk applied to phylogenetics. The bindings I have seen are suited to document databases (MongoDB, CouchDB). You will be fine if your data is document-oriented or you need replication. On the other side it seems there is no binding for column data stores in Smalltalk yet, so I did some workarounds there. But I am afraid I cannot provide a comprehensive answer because the question is closed (?).

Comment: "Are there libraries or applications for dealing with big data in Smalltalk?" seems a valid question.